# How to program DSP inside ADAU1772 codec?

Tags: audio, dsp

I have read ADAU1772 audio codec datasheet but there is no information about internal DSP's instruction set and how to program it. There is a guide for evaluation board with ADAU1772 but I do not have that board. What is more pins of my ADAU1772 are permanently connected to FPGA so I have to program it using FPGA. I just need information which registers inside audio codec I should write and what are possible instructions. Unfortunately I can not find any information on Analog Devices website.

Comment: Look up sigmadsp software

Comment: I have read about SigmaStudio but I am not able to program ADAU1772 directly using it because the only way to communicate with codec is via FPGA. What is more SigmaStudio does not support Linux and I found no tutorial how to make it run on Ubuntu. I wish I found some instruction how to program DSP in low level way.

Answer (score 3):

The instruction set of the Sigma DSP family [is not available](https://ez.analog.com/docs/DOC-1425).

The only way to create a program is to use the Sigma DSP software.

When you want to load this program into the chip, you can do this in several ways:

- using the Sigma DSP software
- using a microcontroller connected through i2c: but read the docs, it is not *that* easy!
- by telling the adau to autoload its program from an i2c eeprom